# Use virtualbox LAMP on my own desktop

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, lamp, virtualbox

I've got a question about virtualbox. Currently I'm using the LAMP setup locally on my macbook. But now i need more than one LAMP installation because I've different configurations. So I've heard that I'm able to run a virtualbox and start working on my own desktop while I'm using the virtual maschine to run all my scripts. But I have no idea about how I'm getting to start such a setup.

Does anyone know an article or an introduction to get into this scenario? Or maybe anyone is able to list the steps which i need to solve this problem.

Greets,
Marc

Comment: Maybe the question is false. So I wan't to generate this by using my browser on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Just install a ubuntu in a Virtualbox, server version if you are not afraid to use the CLI.
Then copy the VM as many time as you need and you will have your N environments.

If you don't need them to run on your machine and do not want the trouble you could use [dotCloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/#!/signup)'s sandbox to create as many environment as you want.
Here is a [php + mysql](https://github.com/dotcloud/stack-php-mysql) boiler plate for dotCloud and here is the doc on how to install [dotCloud's cli](http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.4/firststeps/install/).

Comment: See main comment. I've now another comment to explain my problem.

Comment: You want to use your browser to create vms... I don't get it. But virtualbox as a tool for that: http://code.google.com/p/vboxweb/

Answer (score 0):

I'd throw away Ubuntu and just use Turnkey Linux. Throw it on VmWare player, you could be up and running in 10 minutes!